# How to remove missing values in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using this sample data which contains missing values in different columns and I want to remove all the rows that contains missing value.

[image]

Data Description is:

[image]

I've searched online and seems like dropna only works for dataframe. But when i create a dataframe, I got an error message 
[image]

```
auto_DF_prep = auto_RDD.map(lambda e: Row(mpg = float(e[0]), cylinders = int(e[1]), displacement = float(e[2]), horsepower = float(e[3]), weight = float(e[4]), acceleration = float(e[5]), year = int(e[6]), origin = int(e[7]), name = e[8]))
```

I guess it's because of the NA, I cannot create a data frame. How should I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `auto` is a `DataFrame`

`auto.na.drop()`

Refer: [`DataFrame.dropna()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna)

Comment: So here is what I did `auto = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Downloads/auto_mpg_original.csv")
auto_RDD = auto.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(","))` Now I create a RDD. Then I tried to create a DF using the code in the original post `auto_DF_prep = ...` but got that error. How can I create a Data Frame?

Comment: That would depend if you are using Spark 2.x

Answer (score 0):

`NA` in your csv file just equal to `str('NA')` which not representing a non-number value.

A null value uses empty string on csv